# using an uninitialized global variable throws NameError

Tags: python, global-variables, global

This code throws `NameError: name 'x' is not defined"`:

```
def function():
    global x
    print(x)

function()
print(x)
```

However, this code works and prints "2" two times:

```
def function():
    global x
    x = 2
    print(x)

function()
print(x)
```

My question is, what actually happens at the moment x is declared as global?

Comment: @FloLie So why it throws NameError if it exists in the memory?

Comment: 1. You haven't assign any values to `x`, which is why `print(x)` will throws error.  2. When x is declared as global, it becomes a global variable, it's scope is not only within the function but outside as well

Comment: @sittsering So does it mean if i don't assign any value to it, it won't be in  the memory?

Comment: It'll be. but the issue is, it's not defined and when doing `print(x)` will result in error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined `x`, resulting in the errors.  Try and make the function have a parameter of `x`.

```py
def function(x):
    print(x)
```

Also, when you globalize a variable, its scope is not just within the function, but in every function/class.

- Carden